# How to git svn fetch + rebase in one operation?

Tags: git, git-svn

I just discovered that even though the `rebase` section in `git help svn` says

> This **fetches** revisions from the SVN parent of the current HEAD and
>   rebases the current (uncommitted to SVN) work against it.

(my emphasis) it doesn't mean that `rebase` *includes* a `git svn fetch`. Naming aside, is there some way to run a **single `git svn` command to do both**?

The reason I want to do this is that I only *write on one branch*, so I want to `rebase` that one and I frequently *read other branches*, so I want to `fetch` those.

Comment: I have no experience with `git svn` but ordinary `git pull` can be configured to use `rebase` instead of `merge` and this way does both steps you want. I'd post an answer if I knew how to do that with `git svn`--just look for an equivalent of `git config branch.autosetuprebase always`.

Comment: It does mean. Just try. First it fetches and then it rebases.

Comment: No it does not. `git svn rebase` does *not* fetch new branches from the remote, while `git svn fetch` does. I just tried it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm also a bit surprised to hear that this is actually the way it behaves.  But, to answer your question, you just need to define an alias:

`git config --global alias.refetch '!git svn fetch && git svn rebase'`

Then `git refetch` should do what you want.

Comment: Fair enough; looks like there's no standard way to do this.

Comment: why on Earth you want to fetch all svn repos just to rebase a single one?

Comment: @l0b0: There's no standard way to do it because it's not a standard way of using `git svn`. `git svn rebase` is designed to get your current branch up to the Subversion tip, so it ignores any other Subversion branches in the name of getting you a useful working copy quickly. `git svn fetch` updates everything from the Subversion repository, and so is frequently a much slower operation. I'm really confused about what you're actually trying to achieve that means you need to be able to do this.

Comment: To make the intentions more clear, one could use `alias.svnfetch` or even `alias.svnfetchall`. This way it is clear SVN is being used as the source for the incoming commits. I am was confused at first by how `svn rebase` works. Especially considering the typical workflow of git without svn. It's too easy to forget to `svn fetch` then `svn rebase` each branch before merging. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 23):

I think you're confusing `git rebase` and `git svn rebase`. The former moves commits up to your current HEAD onto some revision you specify, whereas the latter moves your current HEAD onto the tip of the Subversion branch you're on.

`git svn rebase` *does* include a `git svn fetch --parent`, ie it will get any new Subversion commits on the branch you're currently on, but not any Subversion commits from any other branch (contrast with a plain `git svn fetch`, which fetches from all branches).

I suspect you don't want to do a full `git svn fetch` when you do a `git svn rebase`, as it'll mean it'll be much longer before you get a usable working copy. If you want regular `git svn fetch`es, I'd advise setting up a cron job that'll do the fetch in the background for you.

Comment: Quite an old post but I find it still relevant. I ABSOLUTELY want to get all branch updates before I do a git svn rebase. Why? Because I've had many issues while merging if I don't do this. It's too easy to forget to fetch each branch you want to merge before merging and do this: `git svn rebase && git checkout master && git merge feature` before realizing too late that you didn't update the right branches from SVN. If one is using git svn to support better branching it makes sense to ALWAYS `git svn fetch` everything before rebasing. If you don't `git svn dcommit` stomps on everything.

Comment: If there are too many branches in the SVN repo and it takes forever then remove the `*` from the `branches: ` configuration line and only deal with the branches you work on typically. If you're doing a `master -> dev -> feature` combo, it's easy to deal with only those branches using wildcards and the git config file. This way when you `git svn fetch` you don't get unneeded branches. `git svn rebase` has utterly broken my git and svn repo's in the past because it doesn't svn fetch the branches before hand. It doesn't translate well to me. I could be in the minority here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was possible back when this question was asked, but I think that `git svn rebase` does `git svn fetch --parent ; git rebase git-svn`. At least this works for me. It seems that `git svn` creates `git` pseudo-branch called `git-svn` that can be interacted with using `git`. But this branch cannot be modified by plain `git`.

If you than wanted full `fetch` with rebase, you would call `git svn fetch ; git rebase git-svn`.

To put it in a language of aliases (as the accepted answer did): `git config --global alias.refetch '!git svn fetch && git rebase git-svn'`

Answer (score -4):

```
git pull --rebase
```

You could also configure it so it rebases by default. Then you can:

```
git pull
```

UPDATE:

oops. Need more coffee...

All I can think of is to script what you need..

Comment: @AdamDymitruk: This is *not* about vanilla `git` - It's about `git svn`.